# A two column layout with transitions and divs?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to put a transitioning div next to a paragraph and for some reason it doesn't work?
I'm not that good with html so can someone help me out?

```
.left {
float: left;
clear: both;
width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
margin-right: 0px;
padding-right: 0;
text-decoration: none;
display: table-column;
}

.right {
width: 50%;
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: right;
display: table-column;
}

.left, .right {
display: table-column;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="conta">
<div class="left" id="top"><a href="new.png">home<a></div>
<div class="left"><a>about</a></div>
<div class="left"><a>projects</a></div>
<div class="left"><a>blog</a></div>
<div class="left"><a>contact</a></div>

<p class="right"><a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper interdum facilisis. Quisque imperdiet purus ac tellus ultrices ultricies. Sed massa arcu, sagittis quis tellus laoreet, dapibus dictum neque. Nam fermentum enim ligula, quis vulputate arcu molestie et. Sed libero turpis, ultricies id pulvinar non, suscipit ut turpis. Ut nec nisl a odio laoreet commodo ac vitae orci. In eget sem luctus, pellentesque tellus eu, cursus nisl. Duis fringilla tellus quam, sit amet mollis lacus volutpat vel. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec ultrices nibh id lacus molestie porttitor. Proin quis euismod lectus. Vestibulum a elit mollis, maximus diam ac, consequat ante.</a></p>

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

[Full Code Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wdrpkjap/)

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? This question needs more information (see [MCVE]) to be answered; otherwise we are left to guess, at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking to have fixed in the question, but I'm just going to assume you want that right `<div>` to be parallel with the top of the navigation.

Only thing I changed:

```
.right {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -375px;  // Added this

}
```

This won't look very good on mobile as the div's start to overlap so you'll need to do an @media css statement to update the code after a certain width:

```
@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
.right {
    margin-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Here it is on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wdrpkjap/5/